Scraping em sites Olx e webmotors
Alguns marketplaces colocam limite para scraping . Preciso fazer consultas de preços para enviar preços comparativos da concorrência para determinado cliente, é possível fazer? Ou corro algum risco? Quais práticas posso adotar. Estou operando em Python.
